# server unexpectedly closed network connection gitlab and gitolite

Tags: ubuntu, gitolite, gitlab

I've made some backup image of gitlab and gitolite server using remastersys backup and I reinstall from the image file. The problem is the windows clients cannot connect to the server. When I tried to clone the repo, it said server unexpectedly closed network connection. I don't know what is the solution because there is no problem with linux client.

When I tried to clone the repo via git bash, it said "no hostkey alg" which I have no idea what does that mean.

The server I'm using is ubuntu 12.04, windows clients are windows 7 and XP. I tried to reinstall ssh but that didn't help. Does anybody know how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It should be related to an ssh installation issue.
[This thread](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=4471.15), for instance, describes:

> I was having this same problem; I would get the error message '`could not load host key: ...`' I tried reinstalling ssh from scratch, all that stuff - when I tried logging in from a remote server (openbsd) it would deny me saying "**`no hostkey alg`**" ...
>
> I found out that what I was doing wrong was that when I ran `init.d/openssh keygen`, I was putting in a passphrase.
>   When i re-ran `openssh-keygen` with an empty passphrase, it started working as expected.

---

The [OP Sam Mie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1688895/sam-mie) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159731/server-unexpectedly-closed-network-connection-gitlab-and-gitolite/13162862#comment17931806_13162862):

> I have found I have **to disable SELinux** and it works.
>   See [this thread](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/159951-how-use-putty-connect-ubuntu-2.html):

```
setenforce disable
or
setenforce 0
```

> > Setting it to `permissive` will prevent `selinux` from stopping a policy violation.
> >     It will only report it, but still allow the action to continue.
>
> Oh thanks, I configured in file `/etc/selinux/config` and now can connect to Ubuntu with `putty`.

Comment: Thank you, you save my ass everytime! :)

Comment: I have found I have to disable SELiux as http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/159951-how-use-putty-connect-ubuntu-2.html and it works.

Comment: @SamMie Excellent. I have included your solution (link, commands, and config file path) in the solution for more visibility.